# RxJava break onNext

Tags: java, rx-java

I have an observable that emits long values. Once I receive a long value >0 then I just need to to break the emits and hit onComplete. Is there a better way to do this rather than the hack way that I did

```
long id = -1l;
 methodA()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapObservable(list -> Observable.from(list))
    .flatMap(eachObject -> methodB(eachObject))
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .subscribe(new Subscriber<Long>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                //some callbacks
            }
            @Override
           public void onError(Throwable e) {
                //just say error
           }
           @Override
           public void onNext(Long mId) {
                   if (id < 0) {
                    id = mId;
                   }
           }
  });
```

Comment: See takeWhile or takeUntil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`takeWhile`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/com.netflix.rxjava/rxjava-core/0.11.0/rx/Observable.java#Observable.takeWhile%28rx.util.functions.Func1%29)

Returns an Observable that emits items emitted by the source Observable so long as a specified condition is true.

> **Parameters:**
>
> *predicate* a function that evaluates an item emitted by the source Observable and returns a Boolean
>
> **Returns:**
>
> an Observable that emits the items from the source Observable so long as each item satisfies the condition defined by predicate
>
> ```
> public Observable<T> takeWhile(final Func1<T, Boolean> predicate)
> ```

```
methodA()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .flatMapObservable(Observable::from)
    .flatMap(this::methodB)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .takeWhile(id -> id <= 0)
    .subscribe(...);
```